# D3 draw sub circle

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to D3 and I'm trying to draw something like this

[image]

What I have done so far is here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/834wg3g9/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>
    .cover {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        /* border: 1px solid; */
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }

</style>

<div class="cover">
    <svg></svg>
</div>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // let width = window.innerWidth
    // let height = window.innerHeight
    let width = 400
    let height = 400
    let svg = d3.select("svg")
    svg.attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)

    // let nodes = [
    //     {'id': 0,'r': 50, 'color': '#E8837B'},
    //     {'id': 1,'r': 100, 'color': '#FBCB43'},
    //     {'id': 2,'r': 150, 'color': '#16A05D'},
    //     {'id': 3,'r': 200, 'color': '#4C8BF5'},
    // ]

    let nuts = [
        {r: 15},
        {r: 15},
        {r: 15},
        {r: 15},
        {r: 15},
        {r: 15},
    ]

    let nodes = [
        {'id': 3,'r': 400, 'color': '#E8837B'},
        {'id': 1,'r': 330, 'color': '#FBCB43'},
        {'id': 2,'r': 250, 'color': '#16A05D'},
        {'id': 0,'r': 150, 'color': '#4C8BF5'},
    ]

    let simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width/2, height/2))

    let simulation_2 = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-30))
    .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width/2, height/2))

    let nodeElements = svg.append('g')
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append('circle')
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr('r', function(d) {
            return d.r
        })
        .attr('fill', function(d) {
            return d.color
        })

    let bottomLineElements = svg.append('g')
    .selectAll('text')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append('text')
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.color
        })

    let nutElements = svg.append('g')
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(nuts)
    .enter().append('circle')
        .attr('fill', 'white')
        .attr('r', function(d) { return d.r })

    simulation_2.nodes(nuts)
    .on('tick', function() {
        nutElements
        .attr('cx', function (d) { return d.x })
        .attr('cy', function (d) { return d.y })
    })
    simulation.nodes(nodes)
    .on('tick', function() {
        nodeElements
        .attr('cx', function (d) { return 400 })
        .attr('cy', function (d) { return 400 })
        bottomLineElements
        .attr('x', function (d) { return 20 + (d.id * 80) })
        .attr('y', function (d) { return 400 })
    })

</script>
```

Now I'm stuck at draw "New or moved" and "No change" part
How can append a bunch of sub circle to each area and make sure they don't display in wrong area

For example: 
hold = [{}, {}, {}] 
so 3 small circles will display in Hold area

Any advice, keywords to solve this
Thank you.

Comment: you will need to use scales and maybe axis for those

Comment: can you add an example of the circles data?

Comment: let nodes = [
    {'id': 3,'r': 400, 'color': '#E8837B', 'name': 'hold', 'nuts': [{}, {}, {}]},
    {'id': 1,'r': 330, 'color': '#FBCB43', 'name': 'assess','nuts': [{}, {}, {}]},
    {'id': 2,'r': 250, 'color': '#16A05D', 'name': 'trail','nuts': [{}, {}, {}]},
    {'id': 0,'r': 150, 'color': '#4C8BF5', 'name': 'adopt','nuts': [{}, {}, {}]},
]

Comment: Basically, I want each area (hold, assess, trail, adopt) has 3 small circles